# Sql delete value from database

Tags: sql

I have a table main with an id and sec_id. I have the sec_id and I need the id to delete something from the db.

```
 DELETE FROM main WHERE id = (get all elements where sec_id is the same)
```

Comment: delete from main where id = (select * from main where sec_id = @sec_id)

Comment: When you are trying to use the `ID` = something, you can't select all fields from the table. It has to only be the `ID` field.

Comment: so something like select id from main where sec_id = @sec_id?

Comment: What do you mean for sec_id is the same?

Comment: I think Invent-Animate was suggesting `delete from main where id = (select id from main where sec_id = @sec_id)`

Comment: But I would imagine that would give the same results as tvanfossen's `DELETE FROM main WHERE sec_id = @sec_id` below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you should simply be able to delete based on the `sec_id`.  This assumes that it is part of the table.

```
DELETE FROM main WHERE sec_id = @sec_id
```

In this example `@sec_id` is the value of the corresponding `sec_id` that you want to match

If it's not part of the table but you have another table that contains both, then I you might use something like:

```
DELETE FROM main 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM other 
             WHERE main.id = other.id AND other.sec_id = @sec_id)
```

Comment: and what if it's not part of the table?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your table and what you want to delete.

Comment: @user2321611 I added that option to my answer. It's difficult to give you an exact answer since you don't supply the schema

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well:

`DELETE FROM main WHERE id in (SELECT DISTINCT A.id FROM main AS A INNER JOIN main AS B ON A.sec_id=B.sec_id)`